# Does every wordpress theme allow to add custom header and footer?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

The `Twenty Twenty-Two` and `Twenty Twenty-Three` themes have a folder named `parts`, where I placed my `footer.html` and `header.html` files and it displayed this header and footer in my browser(screenshot attached).
But not every theme in WordPress allows to add custom components and don't have a `parts` folder as they have their own `header.php` and `footer.php` files. Is there a way to add a custom header and footer in other themes as well?[image]

Comment: Theme dependent, this is.

Comment: So, is there an option to add our "header.html" file in a theme that doesn't have a parts folder? It actually has a "header.php" file, but I don't know how to add HTML code snippet in php code.